# How to prevent current navigation headings to convert to links when creating site from template?

Tags: navigation, site-template, quick-launch

I've created a template site in SP2010, which will be used to create additional sites. I've noticed an issue with the current navigation (aka quick launch menu) when creating a site using this template. I have headings in the current navigation, some of which are links to site pages and others which are meant to organize additional links (also to other site pages) in the menu. The 'organizational' headings aren't meant to point to anywhere, only to group the sublinks.

For some reason, though, when I create a site using this template the 'organizational' headings become links which point to non-existent sites. For example: a heading titled "Planning" will point to https://site.domain.com/SiteTitle/Planning (note the lack of a page extension as well) when the template has no such URL.

My questions are: does anyone know why this is happening? I theorize that it has to do with SP's automated creation process, which will create the headings as links and does not look at exactly how they are configured in the template.
Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Is there a simple solution that would not require much programming/development?

I've also created another template, whose menu only consists of these 'organizational' headings. It also performs this same behavior. At least it's consistent... I've attempted modifying the headings to remove the URL addresses, but leaving the field blank does not retain the change. It simply reverts back. The only fix I've found for this is to manually create new headings, migrate the sublinks to underneath the new heading, and then delete the old heading. This is cumbersome and wastes too much time. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

NOTE: The reason I need these to retain their non-link attribute is because of a jQuery solution I've modified ([source 1](https://wiki.base22.com/display/btg/How+to+do+an+accordion+effect+to+quick+launch+menu+with+jQuery+in+Sharepoint+2010), [source 2](http://www.lifeinsharepoint.co.uk/2011/12/15/quick-tip-jquery-accordion-quick-launch/)) to have our current navigation collapsible with an accordion effect.

Comment: Did you possibly have the solution to this?? I need the exact same thing and was wondering if you possibly had the solution to share. Thanks!

Comment: @Kam Yes, I provided my own solution in the second paragraph of the self-answer below. An additional clarification: the hash (#) is used to point to an element ID on the page, but no name is being provided so the headings route to nowhere. This is normal browser behavior. You could also use jQuery and [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) on the click event for those elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My theory is correct. SharePoint does not respect the non-URL configuration of the headings in the template, and forces the new headings to point to the root directory. I'd like to also note that it is not consistent and sometimes points to non-existent folders in root.

To solve this, the links in the template will point to /#, and using javaScript I'll strip out the link attributes from headings which have child items (which I've already identified for the accordion current navigation solution).